# Azure Frontdoor -Session values missing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, session-variables, azure-front-door

We have enabled `Azure Frontdoor` for our web app, so when we try to get some session values, we get a `null reference`.But in case if we disable the `Frontdoor` it is working fine. Otherwise when it is `enabled` we often get null reference errors.
And when I implemented logs and checked, I get an

```cs
"Object reference is not set to an instance" in this part of **Code:
```

```cs
 return (guid)SessionHelper.Retrieve (Session.scope.global, key)
```

Can someone help me to know, Is anything missing with the front door configuration or setting session values

Comment: Check if the `Session Affinity` is enabled in `Azure Front Door` => `Advanced Settings`. If Yes, Disable it and check once.

Comment: Yes,we tried disabling it multiple times.We get errors when we try to retrieve the session.

Answer (score 0):

> The error  "Object reference is not set to an instance" in this part of **Code:

- Shows that you are trying to access an object that has not been instantiated / initialized properly.
- Enabling azure Front door will be affecting the session state, causing the null reference error when you trying to access session values.
- To overcome this issue, you can follow the below steps:

1. Check if the session state is being properly initialized and maintained across requests.
2. Check the Azure Front door configuration to see if it is affecting the session state in any way.
3. Check if any dependencies used in the code are null and causing the error.
4. If possible, try to isolate the code causing the error and debug it.

- More details on session follow the link [Session affinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/routing-methods#session-affinity)
- To create an Azure Front Door, follow the below doc
  [Quickstart: Create a Front Door for a highly available global web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door)